# C# using a new class to utilise a forms controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, charts

I would like to create a new dynamic chart control.

This chart will have a lot of code behind it that works out data calculations and then populates properties of the chart.

My form class is getting rather large and I'm now thinking of putting all this new code im going to create in a new class (possibly call it "DynmChart").

Normally to use controls I would create a new class and then instantiate the form in the new class.

But my form class is part of a winforms project that uses program.c as its main class.
main contains application.run Form1.

So how would I create all the code etc that calculates and then populates controls that are in my form.

Here's all my code.

2 classes

Form1
Program

```
namespace RepSalesNetAnalysis
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    float top = 0;
    float tmid = 0;
    float bmid = 0;
    float bottom = 0;
    float tempTop = 0;
    float tempMidt = 0;
    float tempMidB = 0;
    float tempBot = 0;
    string meh;   
    DataTable pgTable = new DataTable();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox2.Visible = false; 

    }

    //button to run SalesFigures
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
        string acct = accCollection.Text;
        Task t = new Task(() => GetsalesFigures(acct));
        t.Start(); 
    }

    //invoke method for setting the picture box visible(grabs the control out of the form to use in a thread)
    private void SetPictureBoxVisibility(bool IsVisible)
    {
        if (pictureBox2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            pictureBox2.Invoke(new Action<bool>(SetPictureBoxVisibility), new Object[] { IsVisible });
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox2.Visible = IsVisible;
        }
    }

    //invoke method for a check box toggle(to be used for testing
    private void SetCheckBoxValue(bool IsChecked)
    {
        if (checkBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            pictureBox2.Invoke(new Action<bool>(SetCheckBoxValue), new Object[] { IsChecked });
        }
        else
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = IsChecked;
        }
    }

    //invoke method to add customers and pass it to the sales method
    private void AddItem(string value)
    {
        if (accCollection.InvokeRequired)
        {
            accCollection.Invoke(new Action<string>(AddItem), new Object[] { value });
        }
        else
        {
            accCollection.Items.Add(value);
        }
    }

    //invoke method to set the datagrid properties
    private void SetDataGrid(bool AutoGenerateColumns, Object DataSource, String DataMember, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode Mode)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action<bool, Object, String, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode>(SetDataGrid),
                                      AutoGenerateColumns, DataSource, DataMember, Mode);
        }
        else
        {
            this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = AutoGenerateColumns;
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = DataSource;
            this.dataGridView1.DataMember = DataMember;
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(Mode);
        }
    }

    //on form load run the accounts too combco box method
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutofillAccounts();
    }

    //method for task to get sales info
    private void GetsalesFigures(string Acct)
    {
        try
        {
            string myConn = "Server=sgsg;" +
                            "Database=shaftdata;" +
                            "uid=bsgsg;" +
                            "pwd=drsgsg;" +
                            "Connect Timeout=120;";

            string acct;// test using 1560
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConn);
            SqlCommand Pareto = new SqlCommand();
            BindingSource bindme = new BindingSource();
            SqlDataAdapter adapt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(Pareto);
            DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet();
            DataTable table1 = new DataTable();

            acct = Acct;

            string fromDate = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            string tooDate = this.dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            Pareto.Connection = conn;
            Pareto.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Pareto.CommandText = "dbo.GetSalesParetotemp";
            Pareto.CommandTimeout = 120;

            Pareto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct", acct);
            Pareto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", fromDate);
            Pareto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@too", tooDate);

            SetCheckBoxValue(true);
            SetPictureBoxVisibility(true);

            adapt1.Fill(dataSet1, "Pareto");

            SetCheckBoxValue(false);
            SetPictureBoxVisibility(false);

            SetDataGrid(true, dataSet1, "Pareto", DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);

            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
                DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
        }
        catch (Exception execc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Whoops! Seems we couldnt connect to the server!"
                            + " information:\n\n" + execc.Message + execc.StackTrace,
                            "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        } 
    }

    //method non-task to get customer info
    private void AutofillAccounts()
    {
        try
        {
            string myConn1 = "Server=sgsdg;" +
                                "Database=AutoPart;" +
                                "uid=bsgdg;" +
                                "pwd=dsgsg;" +
                                "Connect Timeout=6000;";
            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(myConn1);
            conn1.Open();
            SqlCommand accountFill = new SqlCommand("SELECT keycode FROM dbo.Customer", conn1);
            SqlCommand pgFill = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT pg FROM dbo.Product", conn1);


            SqlDataReader readacc = accountFill.ExecuteReader();

            while (readacc.Read())
            {
                AddItem(readacc.GetString(0).ToString());
            }
            conn1.Close();
            ////////////////////////////////////////
            conn1.Open();
            SqlDataReader readpg = pgFill.ExecuteReader();

            while (readpg.Read())
            {
                cmbPrdGrp.Items.Add(readpg.GetString(0).ToString());
            }
            conn1.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception exc1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Whoops! Seems we couldnt connect to the server!"
                            + " information:\n\n" + exc1.Message + exc1.StackTrace,
                            "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
    }
    //spare method for testing
    private void spare()
    {
        chartControl1.Series.Clear();
        chartControl2.Series.Clear();

        meh = cmbPrdGrp.Text;

        bottom = 0;
        bmid = 0;
        tmid = 0;
        top = 0;

        double countTot = 0;
        double countPg = 0;
        double percent = 0;
        //ok lets set the properties on click
        //get pareto data from datagrid using count
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            //count total
            countTot++;
            if ((string)row.Cells["Pg"].Value == meh)
            {
                //need to some how count pgs hmmmm
                //countpg
                countPg++;
                if ((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 50)
                {
                    //top 50
                    //top++;
                    tempTop = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Qty"].Value);
                    top += tempTop;
                }
                else
                    if (((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value > 50) && ((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 100))
                    {
                        //50-100
                        tempMidt = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Qty"].Value);
                        tmid += tempMidt;
                    }
                    else
                        if (((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value > 100) && ((int)row.Cells["Pareto"].Value <= 200))
                        {
                            //100-200
                            tempMidB = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Qty"].Value);
                            bmid += tempMidB;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //its over 200!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                            tempBot = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Qty"].Value);
                            bottom += tempBot;
                        }
            }

        }

        textBox1.Text = top.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = tmid.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = bmid.ToString();
        textBox4.Text = bottom.ToString();

        //calc percent
        percent = (countPg / countTot);
        //String.Format("{%#0:00}", percent);
        //display counts as percentage of total
        textBox5.Text = countTot.ToString();
        textBox6.Text = percent.ToString("p1");

        double[] yValues = { bottom, bmid, tmid, top };
        string[] xNames = { "Greater than 200", "Between 200-100", "Between 100-50", "Below 50" };

        //chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);

        DataTable chartTable = new DataTable("Table1");

        // Add two columns to the table.
        chartTable.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
        chartTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(Int32));
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Below 50", top);
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Between 50-100", tmid);
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Between 100-200", bmid);
        chartTable.Rows.Add("Greater than 200", bottom);

        Series series1 = new Series("Series1", ViewType.Pie3D);
        Series series2 = new Series("Series2", ViewType.Bar);

        chartControl2.Series.Add(series1);
        chartControl1.Series.Add(series2);
        series1.DataSource = chartTable;
        series2.DataSource = chartTable;
        series1.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Qualitative;
        series2.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.Qualitative;
        series1.ArgumentDataMember = "names";
        series2.ArgumentDataMember = "names";
        series1.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
        series2.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
        series1.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Value" });
        series2.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Value" });

        //series1.Label.PointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;
        series1.LegendPointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;
        series2.LegendPointOptions.PointView = PointView.ArgumentAndValues;
        series1.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Percent;
        series2.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Percent;
        series1.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Precision = 0;
        series2.LegendPointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Precision = 0;

        // Adjust the value numeric options of the series.
        series1.Label.PointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Percent;
        //series2.Label.PointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Percent;
        series1.Label.PointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Precision = 0;
        //series2.Label.PointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Precision = 0;

        // Adjust the view-type-specific options of the series.
        ((Pie3DSeriesView)series1.View).Depth = 20;
        ((Pie3DSeriesView)series1.View).ExplodedPoints.Add(series1.Points[0]);
        ((Pie3DSeriesView)series1.View).ExplodedPoints.Add(series1.Points[1]);
        ((Pie3DSeriesView)series1.View).ExplodedPoints.Add(series1.Points[2]);
        ((Pie3DSeriesView)series1.View).ExplodedPoints.Add(series1.Points[3]);
        ((Pie3DSeriesView)series1.View).ExplodedDistancePercentage = 20;
        //((BarSeriesView)series2.View).


        chartControl2.Legend.Visible = true;
        chartControl1.Legend.Visible = true;

        //series1.Label.PointOptions.ValueNumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Currency;

    }

    //spare button for testing
    private void tempButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        spare();
        SpendsAnalysis();
    }

    private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void Piebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*Rectangle tabArea;
        RectangleF tabTextArea;

        Bitmap B = new Bitmap(250, 250, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        tabArea = new Rectangle(1, 1, 240, 240);
        tabTextArea = new RectangleF(1, 1, 240, 240);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(B))
        {
            int i1 = bottom;
            int i2 = bmid;
            int i3 = tmid;
            int i4 = top;

            float total = i1 + i2 + i3 + i4;
            float deg1 = (i1 / total) * 360;
            float deg2 = (i2 / total) * 360;
            float deg3 = (i3 / total) * 360;
            float deg4 = (i4 / total) * 360;

            Font font = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Empty, 0);

            Brush b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkRed);
            Brush b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkOrange);
            Brush b3 = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGray);
            Brush b4 = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkViolet);

            //g.DrawRectangle(p, tabArea);

            g.DrawPie(p, tabTextArea, 0, deg1);
            g.FillPie(b1, tabArea, 0, deg1);
            g.DrawPie(p, tabTextArea, deg1, deg2);
            g.FillPie(b2, tabArea, deg1, deg2);
            g.DrawPie(p, tabTextArea, deg2 + deg1, deg3);
            g.FillPie(b3, tabArea, deg2 + deg1, deg3);
            g.DrawPie(p, tabTextArea, deg3 + deg2 + deg1, deg4);
            g.FillPie(b4, tabArea, deg3 + deg2 + deg1, deg4);

            //set picturebox3 as data source??
            pictureBox3.Image = B;

            textBox1.Text = top.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = tmid.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = bmid.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = bottom.ToString();
            //chart1.DataBind(x);
        }*/
    }

    //need to create a more dynamic chart that will give details via PG.
    //iether by internal filtering OR via queries(queries take time)

    private void ChartByPrdGrp()
    {
        //sort data from frid via grp
        foreach (DataGridViewRow pgrow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((string)pgrow.Cells["Pg"].Value == meh)
            {
                //add this row to new table called boots
                pgTable.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows);//this?
                pgTable.Rows.Add(pgrow);//or this?
            } 
        }
    }

    private void SpendsAnalysis()
    {
        float tempQtypg = 0;
        float tempPricepg = 0;
        double tempTotpg = 0;
        double totalpg = 0;
        float tempQty = 0;
        float tempPrice = 0;
        float tempTot = 0;
        float total = 0;
        float qtyPg = 0;
        float qty = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            tempQty = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Qty"].Value);
            tempPrice = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Unit"].Value);

            tempTot = tempQty * tempPrice;
            total += tempTot;
            qty += tempQty;

            if ((string)row.Cells["Pg"].Value == meh)
            {
                //tempQty = (float)row.Cells["Qty"].Value;
                tempQtypg = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Qty"].Value);
                tempPricepg = Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Unit"].Value);

                tempTotpg = tempQtypg * tempPricepg;
                totalpg += tempTotpg;
                qtyPg += tempQtypg;
            }
        }
        textBox12.Text = total.ToString("c");
        textBox7.Text = totalpg.ToString("c");
        textBox13.Text = qty.ToString();
        textBox8.Text = qtyPg.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

program class is my MAIN class:

```
namespace RepSalesNetAnalysis
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new Form1()); 
    } 
  }
}
```

any help would be great!
Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It wasn't closed because of your bad spelling and grammar but because it was way too broad...

Comment: yup so ive attempted to make a better one.  Any better? or is it still to broad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right...

DynmChart should probably be created as a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and used on forms where it's needed.

However, if you stay with your current approach:

You can use [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) to separate responsibilities between the `Form1` class (or your UserControl if you go that route) and a new `Calculation` class.  The UI class would be responsible for display tasks, while the `Calculation` class would be responsible for number crunching.  Simply create an instance of Calculation in Form1/your UserControl and use the `Calculation` instance to return results of the various calculations you need.

If the UI portion of your control is becoming unmanageable in terms of the amount of code in one file, the first thing to consider is using [#region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) directives to hide parts of the code you are not working on (organize the code into blocks that logically belong together).

Another approach, if you need a lot of UI code and it's bloating your class file, is to use [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for you comments.  ive already got a partial class thats part of the form1 class, this simply creates all the controls.

Comment: moving all my data crunching to a seperate class seems difficult as im using a task object from threads. so im worried i wont be able to get it working if i start swapping in and out.

Comment: @Steven: You will be far better off in the long run if you take time to learn how to organize code properly, even if this project takes longer.  The more responsibility individual classes take on (and indirectly, the larger the file gets), the harder it will be to understand and evolve your own code.

Comment: could you any one give me a hint when looking at my code, is this ok so far? is this making your eyes bleed? "X would be better here" or "do Y at this Z" etc.